# Java alternative code in Pascal

Tags: java, for-loop, pascal

just a simple question I was dealing with recently.. 
what would be the alternative of this code in Pascal? Is it even possible to accomplish with similar syntax?

```
for (i=1; i<11; i++) {

    j= x*10;
    x= x+1;

}
```

The issue is, that in the for loop I am basically assigning the desired range for i as well as an operation (increment i) on the same line.

With Pascal I would only be able to do

```
FOR i:=1 to 10 DO
```

but then, once inside the loop I am unable to control the variable involved in the loop condition (i). And this produces different outcome.

Comment: Even in the Java code you don't 'control the variable involved in the loop condition'. You only change `j` and `x`. What is your question?

Comment: You're not using 'i' in your java code either or am I going blind? :) What do you mean by controlling the variable involved in the loop condition by the way? You mean to change it inside the loop?

Answer (score 3):

The *for* statements in Java and Pascal are very different. In Java, like in most "curly brace languages" derived from C, the for statement is basically a *while* loop in disguise: `for (x; y; z) { P; }` does the same thing as `x; while (y) { P; z; }` (well, not exactly the same thing, there is a difference in the scope of the variables used). In Pascal, the *for* statement iterates over a number of values which are known beforehand, much like Java's *for each* statement (`for (int i : intArray) { ... }`).

Theoretically, there is a big difference in *while* loops and *for* loops: In a *while* loop it is not necessarily the case that the loop condition will ever be *false*, so it could loop forever. A *for* loop we know the number of iterations beforehand. This makes a *for* loop less powerful than a *while* loop, but it is guaranteed that a *for* loop will always terminate. In practical programming languages, the distinction between the two is a bit blurred, but is important to know that the C/Java *for* loop is closer to a theoretical *while* loop, while the Pascal *for* behaves more like the theoretical *for* loop. (This is also the reason that in many, but not all, Pascal dialects you cannot modify the loop variable from within a *for* loop.)

So, indeed, your example does not work with a Pascal *for* loop, but of course you can use the Pascal *while* loop to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I had to read this 3x in a row to fully understand this :D But this is exactly what I was uncertain about. Great explanation, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to (quote from your Q.)

> control the variable involved in the loop

then you can use an infinite **while** loop and count inside the loop. Use the control flow operators **break** and **continue** to exit or to shorten an iteration accordingly, for example

```
var
  counter, j, x: Integer;

counter := 0;
while(true) do begin
  inc(counter)
  // if counter > 10 then break;
  // if somethingelse then break/continue
  // etc.
end;
```

Comment: hmm, thank you. I've never came across this while and break combination in Pascal before. I was trying to code this into 'runable' format, but didn't go well.. would you mind reiterating your code more specifically, so it does essentially the same as the Java code above?

Comment: No, but as the purpose of your Q. seemed to be *modify the iteration index* inside the loop, as you said `control the variable involved in the loop ` then I show you how.

Comment: well, yes.. _for ( variable initialization; condition; variable update )_ this is a definition for the for loop in C. In Pascal, I am missing the 'variable update' so I was trying to increment that  _inside_ of the loop, which gives me the error "assignment to FOR-Loop variable" - which perfectly makes sense from the logical standpoint. But it's obviously not a way to go.

Comment: Actually you were simply confused about the **for to** statement ! It was not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal FOR is a stricter counting loop, whích is more easily optimized by the compiler. A Pascal compiler typically can do heavier optimisation with less effort.

Some Pascal dialects have an optional `step` part, comparable with `i += N'.

```
i := 1;
while i < 10 do
    begin
        ...
        inc(i);
    end
```